# Stop Ehcache store null values

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I have a application use ehcache version: 2.9.0 and i want not store QueryCache who return null values.

Searching i found this link:
http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/cachenull.html

And to implement the cachenull above, found this ideia:
https://gist.github.com/bivas/1196809

I implemented the CacheEventListener to remove null objects key, like in the github link, but not work because the element.getObjectValue() is never NULL even the select result is null.

Displaying the content of the queryCache:

1) - First select, no found the pessoaID = 999, therefore result is null

```java
Element: [ 
key = sql: select pessoa0_.PESSOA as PESSOA1_14_, from schema.PESSOA pessoa0_ where pessoas0_.ID=?; parameters: ; named parameters: {pID=999}; 
transformer: org.hibernate.transform.CacheableResultTransformer@110f2, 
keyValue=[6119085270048768], 
version=1, 
hitCount=0, 
CreationTime = 1493917302268, 
LastAccessTime = 1493917302268 ]
```

2) - Second select, found the pessoaID = 1

```java
Element: [ 
key = sql: select pessoa0_.PESSOA as PESSOA1_14_, from schema.PESSOA pessoa0_ where pessoas0_.ID=?; parameters: ; named parameters: {pID=999}; 
transformer: org.hibernate.transform.CacheableResultTransformer@110f2, 
keyValue=[6119085270048768, 1],
version=1, 
hitCount=0, 
CreationTime = 1493917304047, 
LastAccessTime = 1493917304047 ]
```

**P.S: Attention to 'keyValue'. Is a ArrayList(saw in debug, because the return of method getObjectValue() is an Object) and have a constant number: 6119085270048768 only in first select and the second select have 6119085270048768 and the return of select: 1**

How make this verification of object value? In other words, how disable ehcache to store null-values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach developed by me, sounds a little "code smell", but works.

```java
@Override
public void notifyElementPut(final Ehcache cache, final Element element) throws CacheException {

   Map elementValue = (Map) element.getObjectValue();
   if(elementValue.size() <= 1){
       remove(element);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-query-cache-work/), the first argument is a monotonically incrementing timestamp value which is used for data consistency when comparing the query cache result with the underlying table spaces modifications.

The empty result gets cached, and that's not really a problem because you can reuse this query result as long as no one modifies the underlying entities.

Why would you want to disable the empty results for being cached? I think the current approach is the right one, and I don't think there is any setting that will make the empty result from not being cached.

Comment: Vlad, there anothers systems writing into my database, so in a moment the select can not found anything (return null), but a period next the register was inserted. If not execute: evictQueryRegion("my_region_query_cache"), the select never will return correct.

Comment: You need to use the expiry time in this case

Comment: That doesn't look like an expiry time.

Comment: Look the exemplo a attached above, It's worse?
Expiry time not work fine to me, because in "my-query-cache-region-1" have a lot of entities select, i will lose 1000 selects because only one returned null?

Comment: Why you don't use the database buffer pool instead and more replicated Slave nodes? This is a consistent method to solve this kind of problem. Query Cache is rarely useful